# Initializing ExportFactory using MEF

Tags: c#, mef, autofac

1. Scenario

   1. Application has multiple parts.
   2. Each part is in separate dll and implements interface IFoo
   3. All such dlls are present in same directory (plugins)
   4. The application can instantiate multiple instances of each part

Below is the code snippet for the interfaces, part(export) and the import. The problem I am running into is, the "factories" object is initialized with empty list.

However, if I try container.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable< IFoo >)) I do get object with the part. But that doesn't serve my purpose (point 4). Can anyone point what I am doing wrong here?

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IFooMeta
{
    string CompType { get; }
}
```

Implementation of IFoo in separate Dll

```
[ExportMetadata("CompType", "Foo1")]
[Export(typeof(IFoo)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.GetType().ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Main application that loads all the parts and instantiate them as needed

```
class PartsManager
    {
        [ImportMany]
        private IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IFoo, IFooMeta>> factories;

        public PartsManager()
        {
            IContainer container = ConstructContainer();    
            factories = (IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IFoo, IFooMeta>>)
                   container.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IFoo, IFooMeta>>));    
        }    

        private static IContainer ConstructContainer()
        {
            var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"C:\plugins\");
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();         
            builder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(catalog);

            return builder.Build();
        }

        public IFoo GetPart(string compType)
        {
            var matchingFactory = factories.FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.Metadata.CompType == compType);
            if (factories == null)
            {
                return null; 
            }
            else
            {
                IFoo foo = matchingFactory.CreateExport().Value;
                return foo;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no ContainerBuilder in the .net framework BCL. Are you using autofac?

Comment: Yes I am using autofac,

Comment: Mhm... I'm guessing that the problem in on the autofac side then... the resolve method belongs to autofac, not to mef. I hope that someone who knows autofac well can chime in. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with ContainerBuilder. I tried alternate approach with CompositionContainer and it worked without hurdles. Pasting the code snippet for modified methods.

```
    public PartsManager()
    {
         ConstructContainer();
    }

    private void ConstructContainer()
    {
        var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"C:\plugins\");
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
        container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it's a [known issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/226) in Autofac, that is currently closed with "won't fix" resolution.

If you remove dependency from Autofac like below it will work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SO24132313
{
    public interface IFoo
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    public interface IFooMeta
    {
        string CompType { get; }
    }

    [ExportMetadata("CompType", "Foo1")]
    [Export(typeof(IFoo)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class Foo1 : IFoo
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return GetType().ToString(); }
        }
    }


    class PartsManager
    {
        [ImportMany]
        private IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IFoo, IFooMeta>> factories;

        public PartsManager()
        {
            ConstructContainer(this);
        }

        private static void ConstructContainer(PartsManager p)
        {
            var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var c = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            c.ComposeParts(p);
        }

        public IFoo GetPart(string compType)
        {
            var matchingFactory = factories.FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.Metadata.CompType == compType);
            if (factories == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                IFoo foo = matchingFactory.CreateExport().Value;
                return foo;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PartsManager a = new PartsManager();
            IFoo bla = a.GetPart("Foo1");
            Console.WriteLine(bla);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks zespri. I tried alternate solution that worked and shared it. Seems you did similar approach. \